# ¿Cómo exportar una variable de un componente ReactJS para usarla en otro componente?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo 2 componentes React (A y B), Necesito exportar esta variable ***url*** del componente B para utilizarla en el componente A

```
const Pagination = (props) => {
const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

let url = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=${count}`;

console.log(url)

return (
    <Container>
        <Paginations>
            <BtnConsultar value="Anterior" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                Anterior
            </BtnConsultar>

            <BtnConsultar value="Siguiente" onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>
                Siguiente
            </BtnConsultar>
        </Paginations>
    </Container>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas "emitir" el número de la página desde el componente B, hacia el A, que es su componente padre, puedes usar *props*.
Tienes 4 ejemplos progresivos con uso de hooks de como se haría: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-lederberg-mgjdu El último es lo que más se aproxima a lo que necesitas. Usa `useState()` para guardar el número de página en el componente B, al tiempo que lo envía al componente A.

En cuanto al código, en el **componente B** tendrías:

```
const page = pageNumber < props.firstPageNumber 
    ? props.firstPageNumber : pageNumber;

    // NOTE: emit page number
    props.emitPageNumber(page);
```

dentro de una función que recibe el número de página `pageNumber` de los botones "Atrás" y "Adelante". Le paso por *props* al componente: `firstPageNumber` que estoy usando para que si la primera página en la número 1, el número de página nunca sea inferior a 1. Otra opción es usarlo para deshabilitar u ocultar el botón "Atrás".

En el **componente A**, recoges el número de página, con el atributo del componente:

```
emitPageNumber={(page) => { handlePageNumberEmit(page) }}
```

que se lo esta enviado a la función `handlePageNumberEmit()`.

Como vas a ir actualizando la URL que esta en A cada vez que se cambie en B, tendrás que mantener el número de página en el estado de A, y enviarlo por *props* cada vez a B. Es decir que B siempre recibe por *props* el número de página actual (no sólo el de la primera página), y cuando se pulsa uno de los botones (Atras / Adelante) envía este número + o - 1, según el caso, al componente A, por *props* que lo guardara en su estado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no pude usar todo tu código, pero de acuerdo a eso desarrolle la lógica y lo resolví!

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente se la tienes que pasar como parámetro

**Componente A:**

```
const A = props => {
    let url = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=${count}`;

    return(
        <Container>
            ...
            <B variable={url} />
            ...
        </Container>
    );
};
```

Cabe comentar que `<B variable={url} />` es lo mismo que `<B variable={url}></B>`

**Componente B:**

```
const B = variable => {
    console.log(variable); 
    ...
    return (
        ...
    );
};
```